# Getting Ghostscript to output in Windows 7 64bit (python programming)

Tags: python, windows, ghostscript

I have exhausted all efforts and am still stumped as to why this simple program will not output a tiff file.  It should only be pulling one PDF file converting it to a tiff and ehancing the image.  I am not a great programmer by any means, but it doesnt seem like this should be to difficult...  I think my problem is I am having a hard time getting ghostscript to invoke at all. I have tried (gs, gswin32c, gswin32, gswin64, gswin64c, gsoso) Still no output... Here is my Python script.

---

```
fob=open('C:/Users/Tanner/Desktop/1page.pdf','r')        
'gswin64.exe',
'-q',
'-dNOPAUSE',
'-dBATCH',
'-r800',
'-sDEVICE=tiffg4',
'-sPAPERSIZE=a4',
'-sOutputFile=%s %s' % ('C:/My Documents','C:/Users/Tanner/Desktop/1page.pdf')
```

Comment: Also tried to set path to Ghostscript in cmd and still no luck..

Comment: What mgilson said. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python

Answer (score 2):

All you're doing with that script is creating a bunch of 1-tuples but not assigning them to anything.  e.g.

```
>>> '-q',
('-q',)
>>> '-dNOPAUSE',
('-dNOPAUSE',)
>>> '-dBATCH',
('-dBATCH',)
```

You need a module to issue the system commands for you (I recommend `subprocess` -- It's in the standard library)

Something like:

```
import subprocess
args = ['gswin64.exe',
        '-q',
        '-dNOPAUSE',
        '-dBATCH',
        '-r800',
        '-sDEVICE=tiffg4',
        '-sPAPERSIZE=a4',
        '-sOutputFile=%s %s' % ('C:/My Documents','C:/Users/Tanner/Desktop/1page.pdf')]
subprocess.call(args)
```

Comment: WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: @user1970919 I don't know windows, so I'm not sure I can help you with this one.  Is it python that's throwing the error, or `gswin64.exe`?  Maybe it can't find `gswin64.exe`?  Or perhaps there is a problem with `-sOutputFile` -- That line looks very suspect to me, but I don't know what the gs command is actually doing here.

Comment: It was actually not throwing an error at all everything is compiling fine, it is just not doing what I ask..

Comment: Windows error code 2 is "ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND". What's `lin`? @user1970919 you can always type the command that the answer generates onto the command line yourself and see what happens.

Comment: @user1970919 Do you actually have `gswin64.exe` on the `PATH`? Or is the current directory of the script the directory where `gswin64.exe` is located? (Check them with `os.environ['PATH']` and `os.getcwd()`)